# Como subir proyecto de Laravel a hosting 000webhost.com?

Tags: laravel, hosting

Bueno pues ya he terminado un proyecto en Laravel y quisiera subirlo a un hosting gratuito para ver su funcionalidad en internet. Ya lo he subido al hosting pero me da este error al acceder a la página principal.

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Al activar el modo de debug aparece este error:

> No application encryption key has been specified.

es laravel 5.5 y he puesto todos mis archivos en public_html
se que tiene que ver con la llave del proyecto pero como lo pongo ?

Comment: Hola, hace poco tuve que subir un proyecto de CodeIgniter a un hosting web. El mismo se encontraba funcional en local y tuve que realizar cosas como, la primera letra de los controladores pasarla a Mayúsculas, adaptar los archivos de configuración, te sugeriría que empieces por esos temas. Saludos.

Comment: por favor habilita el debug de tu app de Laravel para que en vez de ese mensaje genérico te muestre el fallo exacto, te recomiendo no cambies ninguna configuración hasta que no veas el error exacto pues así como ahorita esta no sabes cual es

Comment: Gracias por comentar. ya lo he activado y aparece el error como dices @Alfredo, actualizare el post para mostrar el error

Comment: con el comando `php artisan key:generate` debería de bastar

Comment: es el primer proyecto que subiré así que soy un novato. Pero como ejecuto ese comando si estoy en el hosting?

Comment: @Alfredo eso es erróneo. La llave de encriptación (`php artisan key:generate`) se tiene que configurar en cada entorno de trabajo.

Comment: tienes razón @HCK disculpa el fallo no preste suficiente atención al detalle, gracias por la observación

Comment: como bien me hicieron la observación al detalle que no preste atyención debes ejecutar el comando que te mencioné en tu entorno de producción

Comment: @JuanAntonio lo que debes hacer es acceder a la consola de tu servidor remoto y correr el comando `php artisan key:generate` desde ahí. Imagino que desde algún punto instalaste las dependencias de tu proyecto (`composer install`), lo puedes hacer en esa misma consola.

Comment: @JuanAntonio una alternativa que puedes hacer, es generar la llave localmente y copiarla manualmente en tu archivo `.env`, en la variable `APP_KEY`

Comment: @HCK pues realmente no se que es un entorno de trabajo, no busco como interpretarlo. Lo que mencionas de las dependencias pues los instale de manera remota. tengo que instalar las depencias en el hosting ? PD perdona mi ignorancia soy nuevo en esto

Comment: @JuanAntonio te explico. Un entorno es, por así decirlo, una pc. Tu pc viene a ser tu entorno local, tu hosting viene a ser tu entorno remoto y así sucesivamente. Las dependencias, osea las librerías que utiliza tu aplicación, no suelen incluirse en el controlador de versiones (Como `git` o `subversion`) por lo que se maneja un documento que incluye el listado de dependencias con su respectiva versión (`composer.json`). Cuando importas un proyecto en Laravel se tienen que instalar las dependencias para que pueda funcionar correctamente tu aplicación.

Comment: solo corrijo escribí mal las dependencias los instale de manera local no remota. Por lo que entendí tendria que utlizar ´git´ para instalar las dependencias ? o  cómo? Porque este proyecto que subi no se encuentra en ´git´

Comment: creo que tienen que decirle a tu hosting que tu sitio lo ejecute desde la carpeta public de tu proyecto de laravel no desde la raiz de tu proyecto sino desde la carpeta public